# How can I communicate from Arduino to MATLAB

Tags: serial, matlab

I want to use sensors on an Arduino to control values in a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) program. What are my options for communicating?

I've used [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) to receive data sent via the serial cable, and that strategy has worked pretty well. Is there something similar I can do using MATLAB? I'm somewhat new to MATLAB, so gentle guidance would be great.

I'm not really looking for something like the [ArduinoIO](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32374-matlab-support-package-for-arduino-aka-arduinoio-package) package -- I want to have separate computation executing on the Arduino and occasionally informing my MATLAB program (which will occasionally poll the serial line, I suppose).

Comment: Do you need help writing the code for the Arduino, or help writing MATLAB code to read data input from the serial stream?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in Matlab.

Comment: The serial port is your best bet.  I would define a simple message format bases on your needs.  If you only are doing simple stuff like valve on/off: I would define a start byte followed by a fixed number of data bytes.  If you want to get more complicated send a length byte first, followed by that many data bytes.  Please remember: don't send serial bytes nonstop, always have a few breaks (sleep cycles) in the data which allows the serial chips to clock recover.

Answer (score 5):

[MATLAB Support Package for Arduino (aka ArduinoIO Package)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32374-matlab-support-package-for-arduino-aka-arduinoio-package) allows you to do it fairly easily.

> Sample usage:
>
> %-- connect to the board
>
> `a = arduino('COM9')`
>
> %-- specify pin mode
>
> `a.pinMode(4,'input');`
>
> `a.pinMode(13,'output');`
>
> %-- digital i/o
>
> `a.digitalRead(4) % read pin 4`
>
> `a.digitalWrite(13,0) % write 0 to pin 13`
>
> %-- analog i/o
>
> `a.analogRead(5) % read analog pin 5`
>
> `a.analogWrite(9, 155) % write 155 to analog pin 9`

Comment: If I understand ArduinoIO correctly, all the computation is initiated on the Matlab side and the Arduino just becomes a sensor extension.  That isn't what I want.  I want to have a program on the Arduino (doing it's own computation) that occasionally communicates with Matlab.

Comment: The MATLAB side simply provides you with the functions to communicate with the Arduino. It's up to you how/when you want the two to communicate. The Arduino can write to the serial port and this allows you to read from it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a whole lot about MATLAB, but I found some tutorials about reading and writing from the serial port:

```
s = serial('COM1');
fopen(s)
fprintf(s, 'Your serial data goes here')
out = fscanf(s)
```

`out` is now your received data, and you can do whatever you want with it.

To close:

```
fclose(s)
delete(s)
clear s
```

It is from *[Writing and Reading Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/writing-and-reading-data.html)* (*MATLAB*/ *Data and File Management*/ *Serial Port Devices*).

From your question I assume you know about the Arduino side of things (using `Serial`).

Answer (score 0):

I've established a connection, sending numbers. By just changing Serial.write to Serial.print and fread to fscanf you can send/receive clear ASCII text instead of binary data.

Both matlab and arduino code can be found at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368670/matlab-plot-serial-data-continously

Answer (score -1):

clc
clear all
global value
global value1
global val5
global val6
global val7
global val8
global val9
a=arduino('COM4');
   value = zeros();
   value1 = zeros();
   val5 = zeros();
   val6 = zeros();
   val7 = zeros();
  val8 = zeros();
  val9 = zeros();
for i=1:1000

val1(i)=analogRead(a,0)/2; %incomming

val2(i)=analogRead(a,1)/2; %heater

val3(i)=analogRead(a,2)/2;   %heat sink

val4(i)=analogRead(a,5)/2; %atmsphr

val8(i)=analogRead(a,6)/2; %pressure

val9(i)=analogRead(a,7)/2; %pressure

val(i)=analogRead(a,0)/2;

value(i)= (val1(i)+val4(i)+val3(i))/3;

value1(i) =(val8(i)-val9(i)); %pressure

val5(i)=analogRead(a,0)/2 %incoming

val6(i)=analogRead(a,4)/2 %outgoing

val7(i) = value(i)-val6(i)
    plot(value, 'r');
    title('heat sink temprature');

```
hold on

plot(val5, 'k');

title('incoming air temprature');
plot(val6, 'g');

title('outgoing air temprature');

 plot(val4, 'k');
 title('atmospheric temperature');

plot(val7,  'c');
title('change in temprature');

pause(6)

figure
plot(value1,  'r');
title('change in pressure'); 

pause(6)
```

end

Comment: Providing a code-answer without an explanation on what it does it's not a valid answer here on StackExchange. Can you edit your post providing some informations?